# How to Access SDCARD using Javascript LocalFileSystem in WebView in android..?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, sd-card

I want to dispaly List of Directories in my webview of Android using click of a button in webview only.

The webView is Launched Fine and it is listening for the events but I am getting an exception

`Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined at file:///android_asset/FirstFile.html:11`

Here is the complete code

Activity:

```
public class Home extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/FirstFile.html");


    setContentView(webview);

}
```

}

Here is FirstFile.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function getFileSystem() {
            window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem
                    || 

            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024,
                    onFileSystemSuccessUpload, fail);

            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("file:///mnt/sdcard",
                    onResolveSuccess, fail);

            document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Hii its done";

        }

        function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {
            document.write("URI Resolved");
        }

        function fail() {
            console.log("Error getting system")
        }
function successReader(entries) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                alert(entries[i].name);
                if (entries[i].isDirectory == true) {
                    var directoryReaderIn = entries[i].createReader();
                    directoryReaderIn.readEntries(successReader, fail);

                }

            }
        }
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="text1">
    <button onclick="getFileSystem()">Click Me !!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Provide me an appropriate solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. We need to import cordova.jar from libs and include cordova.js into our HTML page.

Now I can access all directories of my SD card easily.

Comment: can you please give more description about your solution?